# How to get teams chat density change from setting in teams tab app usign teams js

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-teams-js

I need to check if the teams application is running in chat density or comfy mode inside the tab application to update the UI based on these settings

I was not able to find any specific handler or function that provides the details for these settings.
Is there any way to get these user settings in the tab application.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any handler or function available that provides chat density settings details. To achieve your requirements, we recommend you give your feedback in [Teams Feedback Portal](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472).